# Using binary indexers on a multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of the form:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n
  <thead>\n
    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n
      <th></th>\n
      <th></th>\n
      <th>Panama</th>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>Contract</th>\n
      <th>Date</th>\n
      <th></th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n
  <tbody>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th rowspan="22" valign="top">201501</th>\n
      <th>2014-04-29</th>\n
      <td>1416.0</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-04-30</th>\n
      <td>1431.1</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-01</th>\n
      <td>1430.6</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-02</th>\n
      <td>1443.9</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-05</th>\n
      <td>1451.6</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-06</th>\n
      <td>1461.4</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-07</th>\n
      <td>1456.0</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-08</th>\n
      <td>1441.1</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-09</th>\n
      <td>1437.8</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-12</th>\n
      <td>1445.2</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-13</th>\n
      <td>1458.2</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-14</th>\n
      <td>1487.6</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-15</th>\n
      <td>1477.6</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-16</th>\n
      <td>1467.9</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-19</th>\n
      <td>1484.9</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-20</th>\n
      <td>1470.5</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-21</th>\n
      <td>1476.9</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-22</th>\n
      <td>1490.0</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-23</th>\n
      <td>1473.3</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-27</th>\n
      <td>1462.5</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-28</th>\n
      <td>1456.3</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-05-29</th>\n
      <td>1460.5</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th rowspan="271" valign="top">201507</th>\n
      <th>2014-05-30</th>\n
      <td>1463.5</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-02</th>\n
      <td>1447.5</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-03</th>\n
      <td>1444.4</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-04</th>\n
      <td>1444.7</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-05</th>\n
      <td>1455.9</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-06</th>\n
      <td>1464.0</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-09</th>\n
      <td>1465.5</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-10</th>\n
      <td>1493.5</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-11</th>\n
      <td>1492.3</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-12</th>\n
      <td>1452.6</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-13</th>\n
      <td>1446.3</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-16</th>\n
      <td>1450.7</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-17</th>\n
      <td>1454.9</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-18</th>\n
      <td>1462.6</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-19</th>\n
      <td>1486.2</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-20</th>\n
      <td>1469.1</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th>2014-06-23</th>\n
      <td>1468.5</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>
      <th>2014-06-24</th>\n
      <td>1484.2</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>
      <th>2014-06-25</th>\n
      <td>1485.1</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>
      <th>2014-06-26</th>\n
      <td>1482.2</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>
      <th>2014-06-27</th>\n
      <td>1491.5</td>\n</tr>\n
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I do `p<1`, I get 'False' for all the values, but when I do a subset:

`p[p<1]`, it returns some values, with NaN's for the column entries. What logic is Pandas following?

Answer (score 0):

I think you get values if `p < 1` if use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (p)
                     Panama
Contract Date              
201501   2014-04-29 -1416.0
         2014-04-30  1431.1
         2014-05-01  1430.6
         2014-05-22  1490.0
         2014-05-23  1473.3
         2014-05-27  1462.5
         2014-05-28  1456.3
201507   2014-06-23  1468.5
         2014-06-24  1484.2
         2014-06-25  1485.1
         2014-06-26  1482.2
         2014-06-27 -1491.5

print (p[p<1])
                     Panama
Contract Date              
201501   2014-04-29 -1416.0
         2014-04-30     NaN
         2014-05-01     NaN
         2014-05-22     NaN
         2014-05-23     NaN
         2014-05-27     NaN
         2014-05-28     NaN
201507   2014-06-23     NaN
         2014-06-24     NaN
         2014-06-25     NaN
         2014-06-26     NaN
         2014-06-27 -1491.5
```

If need remove `NaN`:

```
print (p[p.Panama < 1])
                     Panama
Contract Date              
201501   2014-04-29 -1416.0
201507   2014-06-27 -1491.5
```

Differences in `masks` are:

```
#boolean DataFrame
print (p < 1)
                    Panama
Contract Date             
201501   2014-04-29   True
         2014-04-30  False
         2014-05-01  False
         2014-05-22  False
         2014-05-23  False
         2014-05-27  False
         2014-05-28  False
201507   2014-06-23  False
         2014-06-24  False
         2014-06-25  False
         2014-06-26  False
         2014-06-27   True

#boolean Series         
print (p.Panama < 1)
Contract  Date      
201501    2014-04-29     True
          2014-04-30    False
          2014-05-01    False
          2014-05-22    False
          2014-05-23    False
          2014-05-27    False
          2014-05-28    False
201507    2014-06-23    False
          2014-06-24    False
          2014-06-25    False
          2014-06-26    False
          2014-06-27     True
Name: Panama, dtype: bool
```